# How to print each word after special character in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have sample.txt file.

```
My,name, is ,ben
My|name| is |ben
```

I want to run a script i.e., run.sh which will print each new word after a special character on a new line.
Output should be-

```
My,
name,
is ,
ben
My|
name| 
is |
ben
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Please, finish the sentence. We can guess the data, we can guess the code, but we can't guess the question itself.

Comment: Can you also include what you've tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for the unreadable data, I am new to this!

Comment: What I have tried so far is I have used to echo -e "Splitting the line into word\n $word" but it not separating the words by "," instead it is separating with spaces

Comment: Something like `tr ',' '\n' < sample.txt` to replace each `,` with a newline? Please elaborate the question, add a clear input and desired output. A 'special character' can have different meanings.

Comment: @SaurabhLatambale, I have edited your post. If that is not what you wanted to show/ask then please edit or revert back. Also is it a literal `\n` or a new line?

Comment: You said *"print each new word after a special character"*, but your expected output contains `My` which has no special character in front of it. Also, why are the words only printed once, even though they appear twice in your input?

Comment: I have added the correct information now guys, sorry I am very new to this and just getting a hang of it!

Answer (score 0):

To insert a linebreak after a sequence of *"special characters"* you can use

```
sed -E 's/[^[:alpha:]]+/&\n/g'
```

Here we consider every non-alphabetic character to be special. You can adapt this to your needs by replacing `[^[:alpha:]]` by a class of characters you consider to be special. For instance, you could use `[,|]` to insert linebreaks only after `,` and `|`.

Alternatively, use

```
grep -o '[[:alpha:]]*[^[:alpha:]]*'
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting, can you please provide the whole script?

Comment: This is the whole script, at least if you read the text from stdin. If you want to process a file, simply put the filename at the end of either command shown here.

Comment: Thank you so much man, it worked just fine! If there is any other favor if I can ask you is if it is possible can you explain what each character is doing there? my command is                    " sed -E 's/[,|]+/&\n/g' sample.txt "

Comment: `s/abc/xyz/g` **s**ubstitutes in every line every (= **g**lobally) match of `abc` with `xyz`. `[^[:alpha:]]+` is an **e**xtended (`-E`) regular expression that matches a non-empty sequence (`+`) of non-(`^`)-alphabetic characters. We then replace each match with itself (`&`) followed by a linebreak (`\n`).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, below is how I would do it (this might not be the best way-- for one thing all the pipes take up a lot a resources, but that usually does not matter much).  In English: add an unused char as a place holder after the comma, swap that char with a CR, repeat these steps for the pipe symbol.

```
cat t | sed 's/[,]/,~/g' | tr '~' '\n' | sed 's/[|]/|~/g' | tr '~' '\n'
```